# Show that a Set S is a subring of $R \times R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Question:**

Prove that$$S=\{ (r,r) | r \in R\}$$ is a subring of $R \times R$.

**Attempt:**

*Proof:* Let $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ $\in R$.

As $(a,b) \cdot (c,d) = (ac,bd) \in S$. $(a-c, b-d) \in S$.

I show that S is closed and S is an additive subgroup but I am curious about my work if that is correct or not.

Comment: If you only look at elements of the form $(r,r)$, then you cannot work with $(a,b),(c,d)$ because they might not be in $S$, just look at $(a,a),(b,b)$.

Comment: I see but the idea of ho to prove it was correct right

Comment: Yes.  If you look at unitary rings you should check that the unity is also in $S$ though.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is almost correct.

You need to remember that $v \in R \times R$ means that $v= (a,b)$ such that $a \in R$ and $b \in R$. Now in order to show $S$ is a subring show that for $\color{red}{(r,r), (s,s) \in S}$ you have

$$(r,r) - (s,s) \in S \ \ \text{and} \ \ (r,r)(s,s) \in S$$